# Unified highlighter not populating 'higlighting' field, and other strange behaviour of 'unified'

Tags: solr

I have found that when I query my core with my new Solr 9 instance, I get no highliting items in the `highlighting` section f my result. I do get data when using `original` or `fastVector`. Why is it so?

[image]

[image]

return:

[image]

while

[image]

returns:

[image]

Also, the new `unified` highligting seems to ignore the 'fragsize' variable that controls the ideal size of snippets.  I'd set it to 100 (characters) but we were sometimes getting huger blocks of text returned - over 1000 characters in some cases.  Secondly, it was amalgamating results where the highlighted term appeared multiple times in close proximity, giving large snippets with multiple terms highlighted. All of the above doesn't happen using the original highlighter.

Comment: I don't know much about the `unified` highlighter, but I did notice this in the documentation: "The Unified Highlighter is exclusively configured via search parameters. In contrast, some settings for the Original and FastVector Highlighters are set in solrconfig.xml. There’s a robust example of the latter in the “techproducts” configset." https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/highlighting.html#choosing-a-highlighter -- not sure if this is part of the issue that you are seeing.